# My Microsoft Azure table storage task using .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have to write a code in C# to edit table entity. 
I have got this far but ".Edit" doesn't exist and it doesn't edit when I run and test. Would you know what is wrong there, please?

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string rowKey = GetRowKeyFirstSelectedMessage();

        CloudTable myMessagesCloudTable = GetMessagesCloudTable();

        TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<MessageEntity>("P1", rowKey);

        TableResult retrieveResult = myMessagesCloudTable.Execute(retrieveOperation);

        MessageEntity editMessage = (MessageEntity)retrieveResult.Result;
                 txtAuthor.Text = editMessage.Author;
                 txtMessage.Text = editMessage.MessageText;


        TableOperation editOperation = TableOperation.Edit(editMessage);
        myMessagesCloudTable.Execute(editOperation);

        dataListMessages.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Edit` method. Instead use `TableOperation.Replace`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.replace.aspx

There is also `TableOperation.InsertOrReplace` that will create a record if it does not exist and updates a record if it does.

More details can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/#replace-an-entity